# Clear cookies for response in AFNetworking 2

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am implementing one simple login-logout controller for my application. I am using a GET request for the login screen and segue to get the secondViewController. At the second view controller there is logout button that when pressed returns back to loginView - But whatever I type in the fields I always get in until I close the app (so the cache is playing part here)

Is there any good way to clear the cache. I have tried to do that by alloc init NSURLCache at the beginning of the request and then set removeAllCachedResponses but its not doing any difference.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to remove all your cookies from the cookie store upon logout:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [storage cookies]) {
    [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach works like a charm with AF2

Comment: Won't this delete cookies for other applications as well? Is this best practice here?

Comment: You app runs in a sandbox, so you don't have access to other app's cookies.

Comment: Is there a reason for declaring the `NSTTPCookie` outside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

AFNetwork uses the shared [`NSURLCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can clear this one by call the 
`removeAllCachedResponses` on the shared cache

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it seems to not work - which is really strange.I put this before I allocate AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, is this approach wrong?

Comment: I tested and the approach by @andreamazz works fine. I realy dont know why the removeAllCachedResponses does not work with AF2, it was the right approach with AF 1.

Comment: Because you needed to clear the cookies not the URL cache, they are different things.

Comment: Yep, I got kinda confused of what exactly should be the right thing to clear